# Stm32 ADC - DMA transfer use only half buffer

Tags: embedded, embed, stm32, dma, mbed

I'm sampling an analog audio signal with STM32F767ZIT6 processor, I'm trying to use DMA double buffer combined with ADC, in debug mode all seems works well until the half CpltCallback interrupt, when it's fired I can see half of buffer full, but when the full CpltCallback is called the buffer still half full, half empty, and the old samples are overwritten, this is doesn't depend from buffer dimension, I've tried with 10 or 2048 samples and the result is always the same.

In debug mode I see that half CpltCallback is fired two times before full CpltCallback call.

Here is the little program:
Main:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "adc.h"
#include "dma.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "defines.h"

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
volatile uint32_t adc_samples[2*ADC_BUFF_DIM];

volatile uint32_t adc_buff[2][ADC_BUFF_DIM];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability 
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_BYPASS;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 96;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Activate the Over-Drive mode 
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

ADC conversions start:

```
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI15_10_IRQn 0 */

    if((GPIOC -> IDR & BUTTON_PIN) || (GPIOB -> IDR & ANLG_IN_CTRL_PIN))        //RISING EDGE
    {
        HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*) &adc_buff, 2*ADC_BUFF_DIM);

        GPIOB -> ODR |= GREEN_LED_PIN;
    }
    else                                                                    //FALLING EDGE
    {
        HAL_ADC_Stop_DMA(&hadc1);

        GPIOB -> ODR &= ~GREEN_LED_PIN;
    }

  /* USER CODE END EXTI15_10_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_10);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_13);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI15_10_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI15_10_IRQn 1 */
}
```

DMA call back:

```
void DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_adc1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 1 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
void HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{

}

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{

}
```

Comment: you show not needed part of code  (+ those silly comments - much more lines than useful code), but you do not show the important one. Voting to close

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP probably lost interest in the question asked. Question with the fragments of code posted has no value for the community

Answer (score 0):

Disable D and I Cache and then try.

Comment: it is a comment not answer